# Is opendaylight a dead project?

Tags: opendaylight

Anyone knows what is going in ODL project? In my opinion, it is like a dead project because of the following reasons:

1- Some of the sub-project are not active anymore but you can still find documents about them. For example, how can I use DIDM in Oxygen release for HP switches? I couldn't install it because it is not available anymore.  What is the alternative?

2- I think dlux is also not available in Flourine release anymore. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: The dlux project was rarely used by anybody. It had several security issues, and the community decided to discontinue it. This was publicized in the Oxygen release. All signs of an active community. If you followed the mailing lists, you would have seen this... and that its a very active community.

Answer (score 2):

No, OpenDaylight is very much active - have a look at all the activity on https://git.opendaylight.org of the many people across all still active OpenDaylight projects.  It's just that some projects, such as e.g. DIDM and DLUX, lost all active contributors.  This is perfectly normal in an Open Source "platform".  If you (your company) have any interest in DIDM and DLUX, then you should step up to (re-)maintain it - that's how the open source game works; there is no free lunch in town! ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your response. If you search the web, you will see the last posts related to Opendaylight dates back to 2016 which confirms my observations.  GUI is one of the basic features of any SDN controllers and it does not make sense to me that all of a sudden an open source community decides to stop it because it lost all active contributors.  Whenever a software becomes confusing for its users then it will lose its popularity.

Comment: Open source requires folks to contribute their time and resources and they typically don't do that for free. Many to most if not all are paid by companies that want to monetize it in some way and typically GUIs are part of the downstream "secret sauce" and therefore DLUX became obsolete upstream. I'd think that would make sense to you. As @vorburger said, if you feel strongly  about an open sourced ODL GUI, then the community would welcome your contributions to revive DLUX. If you feel that ODL is dead and not worth your time then you're entitled to your opinion.

Comment: It is not just about open-source. Look at ONOS project. Why that project is so organized when compared with ODL? That project is also open-source. It took me 30 minutes to setup ONOS for an SDN testbed. The last time that I used ODL for an SDN testbed, it took me a month to figure out what is going on. If I want to do the same thing today, I should start from scratch again because there are significant changes in ODL modules.

Comment: Then use ONOS if it works for you. Sounds like you've already used it so why are you bothering to post here and complain about ODL...

Comment: That is not really a good answer. I just wanted to give ODL community a warning about what is happening. My prediction is in the next 2-4 years, just a name will be remained from ODL, if they don't maintain it very well.  I already designed and implemented a SDN programming framework that works independent of any SDN controllers. So I would like to support multiple SDN controllers as part of the project.

Comment: If it took you a month to get setup with ODL, maybe you should consider working on something else. The first time I tried to use it, it took me a few days. If you consider "GUI is one of the basic features of any SDN controllers", then maybe you should read some more about SDN. There are plenty of ODL/ONOS comparisons out there, and they all boil down to what sort of southbound protocols are supported. ONOS supports mainly OpenFlow, whereas ODL supports many different protocols. There are better ways to give warnings than vague and unfounded Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: It supports everything none of those work in practice. I just downloaded Floruine version. Where is l2-switch module? I suppose ODL community decided that is not necessary any more right? Look at documents and see can you find list of minimum features that should be installed? Look at here:

Comment: https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-oxygen/getting-started-guide/installing_opendaylight.html

Comment: where is that table? For compatibility reasons, you cannot enable all Karaf features simultaneously. The table below documents feature installation names and known incompatibilities.Compatibility values indicate the following: Where is it? Have you ever tried to install basic features of odl? it will be ended up to lots of warnings and errors.

Comment: Have you tried ODL on hp switches or just mininet? Where is HP driver in ODL? How can I change default table id?

Comment: If there's no HP driver then no stakeholder that invests their time, money and resources into ODL has had a need for it or contributed it. If you need it then... Upstream docs are sometimes lacking and not maintained - unfortunately that's typical of open source. What do you expect for free? Perhaps you should consider a commercial ODL distro and support instead of continuing to complain here. Or get involved with the community and contribute to make it better.

Comment: I commend the design goals and the architecture, but I've been struggling for over a year and more with ODL. One problem is not much sample code and even the posted samples don't work with the latest release. Very difficult to make progress that way. Some simple how to code samples that are maintained would be of great help. You can't contribute until you become very familiar with the system. Thanks.

Comment: Are there better examples out there these days with Sodium?  I agree with the comments here about frustration in writing just a hello world MD-SAL app.  Followed the example and fought through dependency issues and one week later I still don't have a working app.  I want to give ODL a chance but I need help.